# how to make SOAP RESPONSE and get selected element into textbox/dataset using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to make SOAP REQUEST xml(asmx) response selected element into textbox or dataset. here's my simple script:

```
Protected Sub SOAPRequest(ByVal tarikh As String, ByVal jabatan As String, ByVal HRMS_asmx As String, ByVal tempuri As String)
    Dim xmlQuery As String = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
                        <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
                        <soap:Header>
                        <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand='true' xmlns:wsse='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' xmlns:wsu='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd'>
                        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id='UsernameToken-3DAJDJSKJDHFJASDKJFKJ234JL2K3H2K3J42'>
                        <wsse:Username>660618055198</wsse:Username>
                        <wsse:Password Type='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText'>fouziah@123</wsse:Password>
                        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary'>3WSOKcKKm0jdi3943ts1AQ==</wsse:Nonce>
                        <wsu:Created>2015-01-12T16:46:58.386Z</wsu:Created>
                        </wsse:UsernameToken>
                        </wsse:Security>
                        </soap:Header>
                        <soap:Body>
                        <GetDataXMLbyDate xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'>
                              <tarikh>" + tarikh + "</tarikh>
                              <datatypes>
                                <NamaAgensi>" + jabatan + "</NamaAgensi>
                              </datatypes>
                            </GetDataXMLbyDate>
                          </soap:Body>
                        </soap:Envelope>"

    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.LoadXml(xmlQuery)

    Dim req As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(HRMS_asmx), HttpWebRequest)
    req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", tempuri)
    req.Headers.Add("GetDataXMLbyDateResponse", "http://temuri.org")
    req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=""utf-8"""
    req.Accept = "text/xml"
    req.Method = "POST"

    Dim stm As Stream = req.GetRequestStream()
    doc.Save(stm)
    stm.Close()

    Dim resp As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
    stm = resp.GetResponseStream()
    Dim r As StreamReader = New StreamReader(stm)
    Response.Write(r.ReadToEnd())
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO4Et.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nQdU.png)

and the second question is, using web reference

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyiCA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot, the code you posted has nothing at all to do with your error. 
The method you are trying to call (`GetDataXMLByDate`) on the service reference takes two parameters but you are not providing any.

I can't possibly give you exact code because I lack context but you need a string and you need an array of `NamaAgensi`. So look at this compared to what you are doing in that pageLoad method.

```
Dim arr as NamaAgensi() = New NamaAgensi(0) { someInstanceOfNamaAgensi}
service.GetDataXMLByDate(tarikh, arr)
```

Comment: thanks you.solve=Dim arr as NamaAgensi() = New NamaAgensi(0) { NamaAgensi.MPIC}
service.GetDataXMLByDate(tarikh, arr)